# mySQL android studio. java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to use MySQL with android studio for an app for school. I'm having trouble getting the commands to run only when I am running with a simulator. In a separate file the commands work fine, and there is no crash. I know using mySQL probably isn't the best idea, but my group doesn't have many other options.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.SQLException
fun getData(): Array<String> {
    // val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Stonks"
    val url =
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Stonks?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false"
    val user = "Shane"
    val password = "pass"

    try {
        //it fails on this line
        val myCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
```

errors list:

> W/System.err: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1006)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
> at com.example.fantasystocks1.MainActivity.getData(MainActivity.kt:94)
> at com.example.fantasystocks1.ui.Search.SearchFragment.onCreateView(SearchFragment.kt:34)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
> Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
> at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1605)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:389)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
> at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
> at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
> at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:621)
> at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
> at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
> W/System.err:     at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:953)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in your log:

`Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

You can't connect to your database on a UI or main thread, use a separate thread, ansynctask, etc. Find more in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

This is an ugly solution, put this before `DriverManager.getConnection()`

Kotlin:

```
val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
```

Java:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```